# ASP.NET routes not working in IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, routes

I have built a small web application in asp.net c# in VS 2010 using Framework 3.5.
I need to deploy it on Windows 2003 server with IIS6.

Its using routes ( System.Web.Routing ) which are working fine when I run though Visual Studio. But now after deploying to IIS6 server, it gives 404 error. If I type exact path of page, it works fine.

like http://localhost.local/forms/user/login.aspx works
but my custom route http://localhost.local/user/login gives 404 error

I have goggled found this [Installing Wildcard Application Mappings](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true) & [Running ASP.NET MVC Under IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 Classic Mode : Solution to Routing Problem](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem)

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Got the problem, I was not restarting the IIS6 properly. I was only restarting the website. Above links were showing correct info how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Goggled and found...

- http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true
- http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem

...but it was still not working.

Worked out the problem; I was not restarting the IIS6 properly. I was only restarting the website. 

The above links were showing correct info on how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

In IIS, .net runs as an IIS extension. This means there has to be something about the request that IIS can recognise to know it needs to send the request to .Net. This is usually in the form of a file extension, i.e. `.aspx`

so the path `http://localhost/forms/user/login.aspx` works because of the .aspx extension

the path `http://localhost/user/login` won't in itself be passed to .NET to execute, unless the path exists and there is a default.aspx in the folder.

IIS7 solves this by elevating .net to an integral part - integrated pipeline.

You might get it to work using wildcard mapping or by using an extension that maps to .net - which is what is recommended for MVC on IIS 6